Cloudkit records disappeared
App crashed showing error index out of range. In cloudkit dashboard, querying the table showed half of the records missing.
No changes were made neither to the app nor the database since the last perfect run.
Checked every where and found a ref that probably the indexing was failing, but the records were still there.
No solution however
After one week the records were still missing.
Finally I added a extra index on the createdtimestamp field on a table
... all records were back immediately, also from other tables where I did not put the extra index
I'm just posting this since I found many similar questions, but never a solution

I added a extra index on the createdtimestamp field on a table
... all records were back immediately, also from other tables where I did not put the extra index
